# Tablesorter StickyHeaders shifts columns over on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, tablesorter

In two separate parts of our software, (entirely different code) Sticky Headers have always done this and we've lived with it. I apply the StickyHeader widget and put these in a .wrapper container, and it works as intended: the header will follow on scroll. However, it *always* causes our headings to shift to the right. My .wrapper is simple:

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative; overflow-y: auto; height: 652px;
}
th {
  background-color: #003366;
  color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold;
  padding: 3px; text-align: center;
}
```

Please excuse the obfuscation, but I am not (legally) allowed to make a jsFiddle or provide any more clarity than this. Notice the second "black blob" is shifted completely off while the rec is clearly off-center.

**Before Scroll**

[image: Before Scroll]

**After Scroll**

[image: After Scroll]

Comment: Are you using the most up-to-date version of tablesorter and the stickyHeaders widget? If you are, please modify [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/f36416oy/) to duplicate the issue.

Comment: Brand new off the site and have been using various versions for years with this issue. I will attempt to reproduce the issue on that demo tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, the issue was the CSS:

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
```

However, when applied to [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/f36416oy/), I could not reproduce the error. I've tried to determine what else in conjunction would be causing the issue, but whatever I tried, it would always resolve back solely to border-box. I answer my own question with the advice: if you happen upon this rare bug affecting your sticky tables, run something like

```
/* give to all elements, excluding report_table */
*:not(.report_table *) { 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```